# Variable in theme_preprocess_page is changed before page.tpl.php

Tags: theming

In my `theme_preprocess_page()` function, I set a variable to a default value. Then, in an `if(!empty($variables['node'])) { }` block, I do various calculations to give that variable the value I actually want.

At the bottom of that function, the variable has the value I want, confirmed by `dpm()`. I set `$variables['my_var'] = $my_var`. After that, `$variables` has an entry with the correct name and correct values, also confirmed by `dpm()`. The function ends immediately thereafter.

But in page.tpl.php, when I `dpm($my_var)`, it shows *not* the correct value, *not* a "variable doesn't exist" error, *but instead* the **default** value I set at the *top* of `theme_preprocess_page()`.

It gets weirder. When I started writing this question, a `dpm($variables['my_var'])` at the top of `theme_process_page()` correctly displayed the variable. I realized that I should have had a test at the bottom of that function as well. When I added it, the variable started having the correct value in `page.tpl.php`! Then I started messing with just the `dpm()` calls in `theme_process_page()`, and now I'm in a state where **none** of the `dpm`s in `theme_process_page()` display the correct value!

I'm flummoxed and my boss is flummoxed. What is there between `template_preprocess_page()` and `page.tpl.php` that could be doing something strange with this variable, particularly to make its value in `template_process_page()` behave indeterminately?

---

### This post, illustrated:

**template.php**

```
<?php 

function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $myvar = 'default';

    if(!empty($variables['node'])) {
        // ...

        $myvar = 'modified';

        // ...
    }

    dpm($myvar, '$myvar at bottom of preprocess_page');

    $variables['myvar'] = $myvar;

    dpm($variables['myvar'], '$variables[‘myvar’] at bottom of preprocess_page');
}

function theme_process_page(&$variables) {
    dpm($variables['myvar'], '$variables[‘myvar’] in process_page');
}

?>
```

**page.tpl.php**

```
<?php

dpm($myvar, '$myvar in page.tpl.php');

?>
```

**Messages area in loaded page**

> $variables[‘myvar’] in process_page => **[Sometimes 'default', sometimes 'modified']**
>
> $myvar in page.tpl.php => 'default'
>
> $myvar at bottom of preprocess_page => 'modified'
>
> $variables[‘myvar’] at bottom of preprocess_page => 'modified'

Comment: Maybe the variable name you're using is not unique?

Comment: And are you checking `$myvar` in a conditional anywhere? It wouldn't be the first time someone did `if ($myvar = 'default') {} `

Comment: I've quadruple-checked both those issues. The variable name isn't used anywhere else in my theme, and I'm checking the value at the last line of `preprocess_page`, the first and last lines of `process_page`, and the first line of `page.tpl.php`. It really, really seems like something is happening outside my theme, or at least outside these two files. I may post my real code later if I don't figure this out.

Comment: Why hook_process_page?

Comment: I have to do some logic on the page title, which isn't available in `preprocess_page`.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe it has something to do with the execution order of the various modules ? Are there modules which affect blocks with preprocess or alter hooks ? Testing for it should be easy and worth a shot ...